# Export multiple worksheets to CSV and specify save folder

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I've got this Macro working beautifully, but every now and again it will save the exported sheets into the last folder I was working in, and not the specific folder I want them in. How do I specify the folder they should go into?

```
Sub asdf()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
   ws.Copy
   Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
   With newWb
      .SaveAs ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSVWindows
      .Close (False)
   End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the location you want it saved to in the code.

Try this.

```
.SaveAs FileName:="C:\OutputFilepath\" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
.SaveAs ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSVWindows
```

With

```
.SaveAs "D:\MyFolder\" & ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSVWindows
```

Change the "D:\MyFolder\" to your desired path.

Comment: Struggling to make this work, probably because I'm on a mac running OS X.  Tried dropping in "/Users/myusername/Desktop" as a path, but it's not working? Any ideas?

Comment: add another "/" after Desktop. "/Users/myusername/Desktop/" Directory locations end with a forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

Add a string type var that contains the full path to the folder. In the following example, I'll use the temp directory.

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook, fp as string

    fp = environ("TEMP") & Chr(92)
    'could be something like
    'fp = environ("USER") & "\desktop\"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
       ws.Copy
       Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
       With newWb
          .SaveAs fp & ws.Name, xlCSVWindows   'add the path, let saveas add the extension
          .Close savechanges:=False
       End With
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain the environ("TEMP") & Chr(92) bit? The Chr(92) has confused me.

Comment: The ninety-second character in the ASCII table is the backslash. The [Environ function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not typically end with one.